# How to ignore or ensure the socket is open before sending? (PHP Crashes on a fata error)

Tags: php, sockets, resources, fatal-error

The following code crashes in a fatal error if the socket is in a closed state. I have tried to get the status of the port, but have had no luck.

```
<?php
 Console::log('Opening a server socket on address: ' . $address . ' port: ' . $port);
        $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
        socket_set_nonblock($sock);
        socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
        socket_listen($sock, 100);
        
        ...
        
        $read = $clients;
        $write = null;
        $except = null;

        // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
        try {
            $reads = @socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0, 250000);
        } catch (Exception) {

            }
```

Resulted in this output:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: socket_select(): Argument #1 ($read) contains a closed socket in /home/ubuntu/xeros/src/Node.php:78
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ubuntu/xeros/src/Node.php(78): socket_select()
#1 /home/ubuntu/xeros/bin/xero(63): Xeros\Node->listen()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/ubuntu/xeros/src/Node.php on line 78
```

But I expected this output instead:

No Fatal Type error..

PHP Version
PHP 8.1.2

Operating System
Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Changing this all to use stream sockets gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Use `Throwable` to catch the socket exception.

```php
try {
    $reads = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0, 250000);
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    
}
```